# Dart / Flutter default date format

Tags: datetime, dart, flutter, string-formatting

I am trying to format `DateTime` result and display it to the user in user's current device locale.

Currently I can either display entire `DateTime` such as following:

> 2018-10-08 16:08:37.464112

Or by specifying exact format like this:

```
DateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(DateTime.now())
```

which results in following:

> 08.10.2018

My problem with this solution is, while this format might be acceptable in EU; in e.g. US (and many other countries) they are used to a different Date format, e.g.

> 10/08/2018

**My question is**: how to return only Date (not time) to user in their current locale's format?

**Answer**:
One needs to retrieve current locale and pass it to the format function. I am using custom localizations class, yet with out of the box solution it would look like this:

```
DateFormat.yMMMd(Localizations.localeOf(context)).format(result);
```

Comment: You can pass a locale to `DateFormat` like `format = new DateFormat.yMMMd("en_US");`. See also https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html, https://flutter.io/tutorials/internationalization/

Comment: Make it a separate article to be marked as answer.

Comment: Didn't work for me, cause `localeOf` didn't return a string so I did this, and it worked:
`var local = Localizations.localeOf(context).toString();
      var formattedDate =
          DateFormat.yMMMd(local).format(myDate);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass a locale to `DateFormat` like

```
format = DateFormat.yMMMd("en_US");
```

See also

- https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html
- https://flutter.io/tutorials/internationalization

Comment: I appreciate your answers but I have a question, why do you still use `new` keyword in your answers?

Answer (score 16):

I know this is already answered, but in case someone wants to use the actual device locale and not a hard-coded one:

```
DateFormat.yMMMd(Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode).format(result);
```

Important, you need to pass a `String` and not a `Locale` object here.

If you want to have a custom date format, then you need to create your own switch/case based on all the locales you want to support.